# ROS Os with Unity Engine

Tags: ros, linux, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone done ROS (Robot OS) integration with Unity?

Unity is working on Linux Ubuntu:

http://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform/desktop

The ROS Os with Unity Engine Would be Amaizing!!!!!!

[video=youtube;dk8gpz0o5TU][https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dk8gpz0o5TU[/video]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dk8gpz0o5TU%5B/video%5D)

The Gazebo simulation environment is very bad, i used many times, so i can say it.....
even Morse is much batter...

Please Answer Guys

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191583/ros-os-with-unity-engine/) by [Researcher - of Unity](https://answers.ros.org/users/20111/researcher---of-unity/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-08-31

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-01**:
How exactly can a Robot Operating System benefit from a 3D game engine?

Or do you just mean Gazebo? In newer versions of Gazebo there are already four physics engines implemented I think.

I also could imagine that the license of Unity 3D is not that compatible with the BSD license of ROS

**Comment by [pavan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25676/pavan/) on 2016-06-17**:
The integration is very useful for research. Unity is great for 3d graphics of life like arenas. ROS is good for hardware integration. People who are working with robots whose actions are dependent on real world objects would find this awesome.

These guys did this!
http://goo.gl/TLGS5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think there is anything Ros-Unity available. This question on the same issue also stayed unanswered:  http://answers.ros.org/question/123641/has-anyone-integrated-ros-with-unity-3d/

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-06-29**:
As in the referenced thread `rosbridge` might be one possibility.